# is there some method that like clCreateSubBuffer in Metal?

Tags: ios, opencl, metal

I am developing a iOS app and trying to use Metal to accelerate the computing speed.
I hope to compute data in different MTLBuffer and output into different segment of the same dest MTLBuffer.
I know that in OpenCL i can use `clCreateSubBuffer`
to access different parts of a buffer with different offsets. but i can not find such a method in Metal.
Any solution? or i just miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the MTLBuffer to the MTLComputeCommandEncoder with a different offset:

```
encoder.setBuffer(myBuffer, offset: XXX, index: 0)
```